# Odd behavior of a JOIN query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In the library management system I'm developing I have a table with a tree of literary genres. They are coded like IPs (code 2. poems, code 2.1. epic poems, code 2.1.2. Latin epic poems and so on).

The IP-like code allows a count not just of a specific genre, but also of all its subgenres. If I want to know how many poems there are in the library all I have to do is to count the `2.%` codes.

Since the tree will be populated according to the needs of the library, when they'll get new books, there is a field named `ord_vis` specifying the visualization order of the rows (i.e. a new line about the Italian-Turkish War of 1911 must be shown before WWI and WWII even if inserted after the Six Days War).

The tree worked smoothly until I decided to count the number of titles with the query below:

```
SELECT  a.id, a.code, a.level, a.parent, a.text,
        GROUP_CONCAT( b.text ORDER BY  b.ord_vis SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS subs,
        COUNT( books.id ) AS total
    FROM  tree AS a
    LEFT JOIN  books ON books.code LIKE CONCAT( a.code, '%' )
    LEFT JOIN  tree AS b ON b.parent = a.id
      AND  b.level = a.level +1
    WHERE  a.parent =42 -- this value is the user query
    GROUP BY  a.id
    ORDER BY  a.ord_vis ASC
```

Oddly, if `total` is > 0 or NOT NULL, the number of `subs` shown is the same of the `total`: with 6 books and 3 subgenres I get a `sub` like "sub1, sub1, sub2, sub2, sub3, sub3".

When `total` is 0, the `subs` are shown in the right number and order.

I've unsuccessfully tested the query with all the JOIN options available, and I also tried to change the order of the JOINs and of the SELECT fields.

I solved the issue modifying the line getting the subs in this way: `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.text ORDER BY b.ord_vis SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS subs` but I want to understand why I got those odd results without the `DISTINCT`.

Any clue?

Comment: Can you do the calculation in script? Eg php

Comment: The result is good adding a DISTINCT in the grouping… but I want to understand why :-)

Comment: In order to know why DISTINCT affects your grouping (which does not seem odd at all) I would need to see your data.

Comment: @TobyAllen - where can I dump a 2,5 Mb table?

Comment: If it works with distinct, use distinct.

Comment: The question was just to have a better understanding of the tools I use, so in case I'll have other similar problems I'll know how to solve them :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` tends to explode the number of rows.  `DISTINCT` is a way to reign in the explosion.

Another approach (that sometimes works) is to us a correlated subquery.  This may (or may not) run slower:

```
SELECT  a.id, a.code, a.level, a.parent, a.text, 
        ( SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT( text ORDER BY  ord_vis SEPARATOR ', ' )
            FROM  tree
            WHERE  parent = a.id
              AND  level = a.level +1 ) AS subs,
        COUNT( books.id ) AS total
    FROM  tree AS a
    LEFT JOIN  books ON books.code LIKE CONCAT( a.code, '%' )
    WHERE  a.parent =42 -- this value is the user query
    GROUP BY  a.id
    ORDER BY  a.ord_vis ASC
```

(I suspect the `LEFT` is unnecessary?)

Comment: What leaves me perplexed is the odd pattern of results without the DISTINCT. I don't think on a search on 10,000 books the subquery will make a great difference, but I'll try it on a testbed table with some 120,000 rows. Without the left the genres without books are not shown.

Comment: You might be able to get a feel for it if you do the SELECT without the DISTINCT.  You will see virtually duplicate rows coming out.  They will differ only because of one of the JOINs.  If you then also remove that JOIN, the DISTINCT will no longer be necessary.  (Sorry, I am a bit vague.)

Comment: I see I had to add a DISTINCT even on COUNT (books.id), because I got a total of over 80,000 titles on a 10,000 lines table: a sort of Ponzi scheme… :-)